# Query- LINQ, 2 tables, Union

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

These are my two tables:

```
publicParking(publicParkingID, address, latitude, longtitude, status,
              PricePerHour, maxSpaces, occupiedSpaces, freeSpaces, isOrdered)
```

and

```
parkingLot(parkingLotID, address, latitude, longtitude, status,
           PricePerHour, maxSpaces, occupiedSpaces, freeSpaces, isOrdered)
```

All of the columns are the same except the ID.

I need to write query in LINQ that will **return a table ordered by price** with all the available parkings (`publicParking` / `parkingLot`) - with `status==true`.

The table should look like this:

> ID    address  latitude   longitude    status

Should I do a union, or should I change the table so the first column will call just ID? (instead of `publicParkingID` and `parkingLotID`)

I've tried this code but it does not work

```
var union =  
         (from lot in parkingLots
         where lot.status == true
         select lot).Union( from pub in publicParkings
         where pub.status==true
         select pub);
```

It give this error :

[image: ERROR]

I am working with LINQPad5 and with code editor of tutorialsteacher. Are there are other options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use `Union` both result sequences must contain the same types. In your example the outer query contains `parkingLot` and the inner `publicParking`.

It could be solved using anonymous types:

```
var union =  
     (from lot in parkingLots
     where lot.status == true
     orderby lot.PricePerHour // don't forget ordering
     select new {
           ID = lot.parkingLotID, 
           lot.address, lot.latitude, lot.longitude, lot.status})
    .Union(from pub in publicParkings
     where pub.status==true
     orderby pub.PricePerHour // don't forget ordering
     select new {
           ID = pub.publicParkingID, 
           pub.address, pub.latitude, pub.longitude, pub.status});
```

But maybe better for further data handling would be a custom class:

```
public class ParkingData
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
    public double Latitude {get; set;}
    public string Longitude {get; set;}
    public bool Status {get; set;}
}
```

and query like that:

```
var union =  
     (from lot in parkingLots
     where lot.status == true
     orderby lot.PricePerHour // don't forget ordering
     select new ParkingData {
           ID = lot.parkingLotID, 
           Address = lot.address, 
           Latitude = lot.latitude, 
           Longitude = lot.longitude, 
           Status = lot.status})
    .Union(from pub in publicParkings
     where pub.status==true
     orderby pub.PricePerHour // don't forget ordering
     select new {
     select new ParkingData {
           ID = pub.publicParkingID, 
           Address = pub.address, 
           Latitude = pub.latitude, 
           Longitude = pub.longitude, 
           Status = pub.status});
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!